# Does DHCP protocol allow a server to offer multiple addresses to clients instead of just one?

Tags: dhcp

This is an exam question of Internet Protocol.

I thought the answer is "NO" but I want to make sure.

Comment: No. It doesn't belong on any of the three sites. (At most on superuser.) Serverfault _isn't_ about things that have to do with servers. Serverfault is about people who manage _more than one_ server professionally and not as a hobby.

Comment: See the FAQ http://serverfault.com/faq: Server Fault is for *system administrators and IT professionals*, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.

Comment: Obviously, what we need is "Homework Fault" to take care of questions like this.

Comment: RFC2131 is your friend.  "Homework Fault" - :)

Comment: Why would you send this to Superuser? Its not just a dumping ground for crap we don't like. The topic of this question is around DHCP, were it a valid question, it would belong on this site. It's a bad, do my homework for me question, so it should be closed as such, not sent over to SU for them to close it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find what you're looking for [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131) (and if you actually bother to read it you'll learn something, as opposed to just having the answer given to you).

Answer (score 2):

A server of this protocol assigns an IP address per MAC address. So YES the protocol can support multiple IP addresses per Host given multiple NICs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the answer is no. not at the same time. (at least if the client have 1 nic)

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, a single DHCP server will not supply multiple addresses to one client and let it choose.

**But** if you have more than one DHCP servers on your network (for redundancy in legacy windows (2003) environments?) a client will often get one `DHCPOFFER` from **each** DHCP server. Then, the client chooses one server to send his `DHCPREQUEST` to. Usually the client takes the server which answered first.

Comment: hmmm.... there is a difference between a "Client" and a "Network Adapter" (NIC). A DHCP server doesn't really know about "Clients" per-se, just MAC addresses.  Have a look at the "byte level" protocol definition to make sure.