# Could DHCP server offer multiple address for a client and let it choose one?

Tags: dhcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does DHCP protocol allow a server to offer multiple addresses to clients instead of just one?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84896/does-dhcp-protocol-allow-a-server-to-offer-multiple-addresses-to-clients-instead)

If the answer is yes, then why does it does that?

The following is the original question:

```
dhcp client sends to server dhcp discover message, server replies to client
"dhcp  offer", which includes multiple ip addresses, the client can pick up one that 
it preferes, then sends to server dhcp request, including the ip that it wants to pick  
up. my queestion is, why server sends to client multiple ip addresses so that 
it can select,rather than just assign it one ip address?
```

Comment: BTW: I asked my friend again, and she 100% sure DHCP server could offer more than one IP to let the client to choose.  So the question is : WHY.

Comment: You were told to read the RFC in your previous question.

Comment: I have read.   And from what I've read, I don't think DHCP could offer multiple IPs to client.  But maybe other you guys know more than RFC.

Comment: The RFC isn't a source of knowledge, it's a specification of how a conformant DHCP implementation works.  If any implementation offers anything beyond that it's using proprietary vendor extensions in which case the rules of the game are thrown out the window and we might as well ask if DHCP can be used for keeping chickens in.

Comment: The duplicate question does not exist any more, but this one is related: [Requesting >1 IP addresses via DHCP](http://serverfault.com/q/383837/62182)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard about a DHCP server offering multiple IP's to a client in a single request. From what I know, a DHCP server picks a IP (and opotionally checks if the IP is ine use with a single icmp ping) and offers it to a client. It's up to the client to either accept or reject the lease.

Comment: I know, but my friend seems to quite sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Time to print out a copy of wikipedia and pummel your friend with it: `[citation needed]`.