# Requesting >1 IP addresses via DHCP

Tags: windows, windows-7, dhcp

I'm wondering whether it is possible to configure a Windows 7 machine to request more than 1 IP address?

I'm doing some testing and it would be useful to have 2 local IP addresses however, the network I'm on is using DHCP so I don't want to pick one that someone else might be using.

Comment: I'd have to do some testing but I believe you'd have to have multiple adapters on the same segment.  Why do you need multiple IPs on the same workstation (without VMs)?

Comment: I'm developing some *peer-2-peer* technology and need to be able to host more than one instance on more than one IP address.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure the traffic would ever leave the machine without a VM solution

Comment: in linux we can use nic alias even if you only have 1 nic, but i am not sure how to do so in windows.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate communication between multiple *peers*? If so, would virtual machines be a more realistic way to simulate your product's actual operation on a local network?

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible. Each MAC address can only request a single IP.

If you need more than one IP, you need to talk with your IT department and request a static address.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know of any virtual network cards for Windows 7. My XPMode VM happily requests a DHCP address over my host's network interface... so it must be possible.

Comment: It's possible from a VM, because that VM has its own MAC address.

Comment: If you can set up virtual network interfaces it is very well possible.

Comment: @tibordp: Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: @tibordp: as he sad: you can only request one address per MAC - that means, One per Network Interface.

Comment: Physical NICs do not equate logical interfaces, and the OP's question refers to the former if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a two-port network adapter and install it, or install a second single port network adapter (even an external USB one would work).

Then plug both in... use a cheap switch if you don't have two network drops.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers, here, but wouldn't you just be able to use something like a laptop, and be connected hardwired via ethernet, and connected to Wifi via your WLAN card simultaneously.

you might look into this application, I don't use it for anything nearly as ambitious, but it allows you to force a an application to bind to an IP address of a network interface.

http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

I mostly would use it to connect to non-firewall friendly apps like spotify, by connecting my wifi to my company's guest network, while simultaneously remaining connected via ethernet able to work within the LAN. but you might be able to launch an instance of your application using this to bind it to the other network interface.